# How is it possible that a user's (positive) reputation change exceeds their total reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

Sorry if this will turn out to be a duplicate question. I vaguely remember something similar on Meta, but I cannot seem to find it (and the explanation I'm looking for) anymore.

Today I came across this on the weekly reputation league page:

[image: Screenshot from reputation league page showing a positive reputation change that exceeds the user's overall reputation]

As users cannot have a negative total reputation, how is this even possible?

The only explanation I can think of is that this user had one or several posts with lots of downvotes, and these posts got deleted somehow; the positive reputation change simply undoes (cancels out) the previous negative reputation changes. But such a huge reputation change seems rather unlikely for a relatively new member (8 months) with not so many answers (around 30) and 0 questions.

The single reputation changes listed on the user's profile page do not add up to that large total given on the league list, btw.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The change is the change in rank, not the change in reputation.

Comment: Oh... that makes perfect sense! I feel rather silly now for not having figured out something so simple for myself. :-|

Answer (score 1):

That change is the change **in rank** not reputation. The reputation change for the week is under "Week Reputation" on the right.